# Code coverage of entire source code in sonarqube?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Is there a way to account for the code coverage of all source code for my solution, even if I'm only including code coverage results that include a few projects? In this case if I add a new project that has no unit tests/code coverage ran against it, it doesn't get included in code coverage % value on sonarqube, so my code coverage stays the same. But I want it to consider new code not being tested. I'm using OpenCover and Xunit for a .net project.

Comment: do you mean multiple sonar projects in different repos, or one repo with multiple projects in it?

Comment: One sonarqube project that has several .net projects in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in SonarC# 6.6, but not in VB.NET. The plugin is currently [in RC](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/releases) and should be released in next day or two.

There is nothing you need to configure, just use 6.6.